# Union of million line urls in 2 files

Tags: c#

File A B contains million urls. 
1, go through the url in file A one by one. 
2, extract subdomain.com (http://subdomain.com/path/file)  
3, if subdomain.com exist file B, save it to file C.

Any quickest way to get file C with c#?

Thanks.

when i use readline, it have no much different.

```
 // stat
            DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
            int totalcount = 0;
            int n1;
            if (!int.TryParse(num1.Text, out n1))
                n1 = 0;

            // memory
            dZLinklist = new Dictionary<string, string>();  

            // read file
            string fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName; // get file name
            textBox1.Text = fileName;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);

            string fullfile  = File.ReadAllText(@textBox1.Text);
            string[] sArray = fullfile.Split( '\n');
            //IEnumerable<string> sArray = tool.GetSplit(fullfile, '\n');

            //string sLine = "";
            //while (sLine != null)
            foreach ( string sLine in sArray)
            {
                totalcount++;
                //sLine = sr.ReadLine(); 

                if (sLine != null)
                {
                    //string reg = "http[s]*://.*?/";
                    //Regex R = new Regex(reg, RegexOptions.Compiled);
                    //Match m = R.Match(sLine);
                    //if(m.Success)


                    int length = sLine.IndexOf(' ', n1); //  default http://
                    if(length > 0)
                    {
                        //string urls = sLine.Substring(0, length);
                        dZLinklist[sLine.Substring(0,length)] = sLine;
                    }

                }
            }
            TimeSpan time =  DateTime.Now - start;

            int count = dZLinklist.Count;
            double sec = Math.Round(time.TotalSeconds,2);
            label1.Text = "(" + totalcount + ")" + count.ToString() + " / " + sec + " = " + (Math.Round(count / sec,2)).ToString();


            sr.Close();
```

Comment: A million urls should fit in memory on most machines. Store the subdomains from file B in a dictionary. Loop through file A look up the subdomain in your dictionary, if it exists write it to file C.

Comment: thanks, now i found  the bottleneck is indexOf, I use it to get domains. i guess it is faster way to get domain. so any better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for using Microsoft LogParser for processing big files: [MS LogParser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13504/Simple-log-parsing-using-MS-Log-Parser-in-C-NE). Are you limited to implement it in described way only?

Comment: no, any way to get file C is ok. but i guess LogParser will be slow for this. because it is not special for this simple job. and it is not easy to use or how to use LogParser to get file C?